# Get url :local/ads.txt to redirect to public/ads.txt file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file `ads.txt` stored in `public/ads.txt` which can be accessed through `mywebsiteurl.com/ads.txt`

But I also want this file to be accessed with the local parameter like `mywebsiteurl.com/en/ads.txt`

**routes.rb**

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    get 'ads.txt', to: redirect("/ads.txt")

    scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
       resources :offers
       ...
    end

end
```

How can I do to access the ads.txt when the local parameter is there ? (I've tried to put the get 'ads.txt' route inside my :locale scope but it's not working. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the `get 'asd.txt'` route redirect, the webserver (nginx, apache, etc) should serve the file from /public without touching your rails app.

For your actual question, you should be able to do this:

```
scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
   get 'asd.txt', redirect_to('/asd.txt') # this should match ":local/asd.txt" request

   resources :offers
   ...
end
```

Comment: Hi ask the question primarly for google adsense that is telling me that I need to add the ads.txt file to my root level (which I have since about a month) therefore I was supposing that I should also include it on my :local level. For the answer, the redirect_to is not working in the scope, neither the redirect!

Comment: What does `rails routes | grep 'asd.txt'` show? do you see the routes for the different locales?

Comment: GET    /ads.txt(.:format)            redirect(301, /ads.txt)
So it's not showing the different locales